# Do we need to fractionally differentiated all features in ML prediction for finance time series?

Tags: time-series

I am reading Prof. Marcos Lopez de Prado's book Advances in Financial Machine Learning, and have a question on feature engineering.
On page 88, he says:
In practice, I suggest you experiment with the following transformation of your features: First, compute a cumulative sum of the time series. This guarantees that some order of differentiation is needed. Second, compute the FFD(d) series for various d ∈ [0, 1]. Third, determine the minimum d such that the p-value of the ADF
statistic on FFD(d) falls below 5%. Fourth, use the FFD(d) series as your predictive feature.

I wonder:

1. Should we scale the result predictive features when fitting a model? The book seems didn't discuss the topic about scaling, is it needless to scale?
2. Should we follow this procedure for all features?

Comment: What do you mean by rescaling? Also, I frankly don't think fractional differencing will have anything more than a marginal impact on your results.

Comment: http://www.mlfactor.com/Data.html#scaling

Comment: The sales point of FD is to keep a time-series stationary and maintaining its predictive power by preserving the long-memory inherently within the time-series. Thus, the use of FD only makes sense on time-series which exhibits long-memory (*very common for asset-price processes to have long-memory*). Whether to scale your results, depends on the FD-transformed time-series. If you plan on using the time-series as inputs into an ANN it makes sense to scale the time-series in order to avoid numerical issues [source](https://bit.ly/3dHtmj1). Try doing both and see if scaling improves model output.

Comment: This paper may shed some light: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12572-021-00299-5